# Recursive function returning None for no good reason

Tags: python, list, recursion, return

My goal is to write a function that takes in a list of integers - `ints` - and a sum goal - `s` - and returns a list of the first two integers in the list that add up to `s` in the order they appear in the list from left to right.  I have the function print to console for every iteration and everything looks good except it always returns `None` and I have no idea how.
My code:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s, a=0, b=1):
    if a == len(ints)-1 or b > 666:
        return None
    if b < len(ints):
        print(s, a,b,[ints[a],ints[b]], ints[a] + ints[b])
        if ints[a] + ints[b] == s:
            x = ints[a]
            y = ints[b]
            print([x,y], type([x,y]), [x,y] is None)
            return [x, y]
        else: 
            sum_pairs(ints, s, a, b=b+1)
    else:
        sum_pairs(ints, s, a=a+1, b=a+2)
```

I even checked if `[x,y]` is `None` in the step before the return statement and it always returns `False` yet somehow the function still returns `None`.  Can somebody fill me in?  I'm new to recursion so maybe the problem lies there.

Comment: Your function is missing `return` statements in half of the cases.

Comment: Put return in front of the recursive calls: `return sum_pairs(ints, s, a, b=b+1)`, and `return sum_pairs(ints, s, a=a+1, b=a+2)`. Also, this algorithm is easier to formulate as an iterative, not recursive

Comment: Klaus has the correct answer. Unrelated, I highly recommend using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I would start writing a generic `combinations` function which generates combinations of a specified size -

```py
def combinations(items, size):
  if size == 0:
    yield ()
  elif not items:
    return
  else:
    head, *tail = items
    for p in combinations(tail, size - 1):
      yield (head, *p)
    yield from combinations(tail, size)
```

We're relying on Python's generators which *lazily* produce the output. We can use `list` to get all of the results -

```py
data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]

list(combinations(data, 2))
# [ (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 3),
#   (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6),
#   (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 6), (5, 7),
#   (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8) ]
```

It can easily generate combinations of other sizes, and the input iterable can contain elements of any type -

```py
list(combinations("abcd", 3)))
# [ ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'),
#   ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd') ]
```

By writing `combinations` as a standalone function we detangle the concerns of our program. As a result `sum_pairs` is easy to write and test. We pass `2` as the `size` argument because we want to generate pairs (of *two* numbers) -

```py
def sum_pairs(ints, goal):
  for p in combinations(ints, 2): # <-- use combinations
    if sum(p) == goal:
      return p
  return None                     # <-- don't forget unsolvable case


print(sum_pairs(data, 13))
# (5, 8)
```

Because we are using Python's generators, `sum_pairs` will return immediately after finding an answer. This short-circuit behaviour means no unnecessary combinations or iterations are wasted.

When given an unreachable goal, `sum_pairs` will return `None` -

```py
print(sum_pairs(data, 99))
# None
```

---

A small modification demonstrates the effectiveness of our `combinations` generic. In this program, `any_sum` will find a combination of *any* size that sums to our expected goal -

```
def any_sum(ints, goal):
  for size in range(len(ints)):
    for p in combinations(ints, size + 1):
      if sum(p) == goal:
        return p
  return None
```

While this is not the most efficient implementation of `any_sum`, it does show how `combinations` can be reused without introducing new complexity -

```
print(any_sum(data, 17))
# (2, 7, 8)

print(any_sum(data, 25))
# (4, 6, 7, 8)

print(any_sum(data, 33))
# (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

print(any_sum(data, 99))
# None
```